# Adjusting intervals in Pandas

Tags: pandas, intervals

I created intervals in pandas for a frequency table. The first interval looks like this: (22, 29]
and is open from the left - I want just this first interval to be closed from both sides like this: [22, 29]. I tried  intervals[0].closed = "both" but did not work.

```
intervals = pd.interval_range(start = 22, end = 64, freq = 7)
vek_freq_table = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,0,0], index = intervals)


for x in df.loc[df.loc[:,"c"].notnull(), "c"]:
    for y in c_freq_table.index:
        if int(x) in y:
            c_freq_table.loc[y] +=1
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct your own interval index with a list comprehension (or loop):

```
intervals = [pd.Interval(i.left, i.right) 
             if no != 0 else pd.Interval(i.left, i.right, closed='both') 
             for (no, i) in  enumerate(intervals)]
intervals
```

Output:

```
[Interval(22, 29, closed='both'),
 Interval(29, 36, closed='right'),
 Interval(36, 43, closed='right'),
 Interval(43, 50, closed='right'),
 Interval(50, 57, closed='right'),
 Interval(57, 64, closed='right')]
```

---

Note: A simpler solution might seem just to change the first element like:

```
new_first_elem = pd.Interval(intervals[0].left, intervals[0].right, closed='both')
intervals[0] = new_first_elem
```

However, this code throws an TypeError:

```
TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations
```